# PayPal credit card payment issue in Android in Sandbox environment

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I have implemented the latest PayPal Android SDK (2.13.1) in my app. I am currently testing in SANDBOX environment. The payment is successfully happening when I use PayPal credentials but when I use the Credit Card option I am getting the following response:

> request failed with server response:
>
> {"name":"DOMESTIC_TRANSACTION_UNSUPPORTED","message":"Domestic
>   transactions are not supported currently in some
>   countries.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#DOMESTIC_TRANSACTION_UNSUPPORTED","debug_id":"debug
>   id is here"}

Here is my Android code for sending a request

```
    PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("1.75"), "USD", "sample item",
            PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PaymentActivity.class);
    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, mPayPalConfig);
    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
    startActivityForResult(intent, mPayPalRequestCode);
```

Also I would like to share that this error is not happening in MOCK Environment.
I have searched enough on the Internet but couldn't find anything related to it.
If anybody has any information about how to resolve this then it would be a great help.

Comment: Regarding 'DOMESTIC_TRANSACTION_UNSUPPORTED",  this error is generally triggered for Indian PayPal accounts.   India country merchant cannot send and receive money from another Indian buyer. So basically domestic payments within India is not supported by PayPal due to India country policy. I am not sure which country your account belongs to . you can use non-indian buyer credit card to have a try.

Comment: Hey @ZhaoSamanta you got it right buddy,mine is an indian account and yes it worked when I used a non indian buyer card